# Aurelia with Bluebird Promise.join

Tags: bluebird, aurelia

I can get Bluebird js to work with Aurelia in the most basic Promise scenario: Create a promise and have an alert() happen when resolve() is called.

But when I try to call other promise functions such as .join I get "_Promise.join is not a function". Can anyone provide some insight? Here is a code snippet.

```
import {bluebird} from '../jspm_packages/bluebird.min.js';

...

activate(){
    test.then(function(){alert('promise returned')};
}

test(){
     return Promise.join(
        new Promise(function(resolve){resolve();}),
        function(){alert('join finished');}
     );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the source code for bluebird.js and found this:

```
module.exports = function(Promise) {
....
```

so I changed the import statement to this:

```
import {Promise} from '../jspm_packages/bluebird.min';
```

and the .join function works now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Promise is not from bluebird. Do you really have `bluebird.min.js` in `jspm_packages`?
Anyway try to add it in `index.html` before `system.js` like:

```
...
<script src="jspm_packages/github/petkaantonov/bluebird@2.9.27/js/browser/bluebird.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
...
```

Also, when you import some script, don't use `.js` extension, do `import $ from './jquery'`

Comment: I added it to the index.html file but that didn't help. I have Bluebird working fine in my app using a simple promise. Once I call the .join function is when it gives me the error.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot that I don't need to put .js on the end. Thanks. I was able to track down the problem and will post the answer next.